# Strange security errors in Firefox on Windows 7

Tags: security, firefox, ssl, ssl-certificate

I've got a client who is reporting very strange security errors I've not seen before on Windows 7 using this [link](http://beek.co/g301/s1301)

The page won't load any of the assets with the error: "this site makes use of a SHA-1 certificate, it's recommended you use security certificates with algorithms stronger than SHA-1"

Here is the console:
[image]

Can anyone tell me why this might be happening?

The site uses a SHA-256 with RSA certificate, and why does Firefox even need to see the certificate, it's not being requested over https?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can anyone tell me why this might be happening?

You are including https resources from sites which are using a certificate signed with SHA-1. If you look closely at the console log and at the links provided you will see access to

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js
https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,100,300,700,900
https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v11/9k-RPmcnxYEPm8CNFsH2gg.woff
....
```

> The site uses a SHA-256 with RSA certificate ...

The certificate of the site does not matter for included resources from external sites.

> ... and why does Firefox even need to see the certificate, it's not being requested over https?

Because you've included the resources as https. Just look at your code and you will find something like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: So I'm reliant on Google, Facebook etc to update their certificates?

Comment: Of course, if you include anything from a 3rd party you rely on the security of this party. And since one usually does not have any influence to this 3rd party this means blind trust that they are doing it right.  But in this special case firefox is a bit to eager with the warnings since these certificates have a expiration in the near future and thus conform to the SHA-1 expiration plans from the CA browser forum.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it is because your site uses an SHA-1 certificate.  SHA-1 is an older encryption algorithm that is now considered pretty weak; Firefox, Chrome, and Windows will stop accepting it by 2017.  You might want to consider upgrading to an SHA-2 certificate.

Comment: Hi Sorry forgot to mention that my site uses a SHA256 with RSA certificate